# Is there a way to add English subtitles for S.T.A.L.K.E.R.: Call of Pripyat?

Tags: stalker-call-of-pripyat

I am Russian myself, and I have, obviously, played S.T.A.L.K.E.R. series in Russian language (the original one). However, I want to share this game with some of my friends who don't speak Russian at all, and I have found out that this game is awfully translated.

1. It is dubbed in English, not subtitled. IMO, this English dub is of very bad quality, I like the original much more.
2. At the same time, some lines are not dubbed (and hence not translated at all!), so an English-speaking player wouldn't understand what goes on.
3. I did a quick Google search, it did not yield anything.

I liked that Source games where you could easily turn subtitles on, reading stuff in any language you want, but listening to it as it was originally done.

Any option to do the same with S.T.A.L.K.E.R. series, particularly "Call of Pripyat", so I can reliably advise the game for my non-Russian friends?

Comment: Apparently, I have to return to primary school and learn to read again. Found a guide. http://kurivaim1.blogspot.ru/2015/11/how-to-fixrun-stalker-call-of-pripyat-by-replacing-english-vocals.html As I cannot give a link-only anwer, I will write my own guide here a bit later if noone else does it for me and my non-Russian friends.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with self-answering - go for it

Comment: @JonK I know that there is nothing wrong -- but I have no time right now. I will do it later. But someone can hijack that opportunity and get a bit of (almost) free rep.

Comment: After watching the video again, I have found out that this doesn't add subtitles for everything like the Source games can have, it only returns Russian voice. Very sad.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but I play the english version of the game and find the translation to be totally fine.  Can't your non-russian-speaking friends just get the english version of the game?

Comment: @Selvek This question if the transletion is good or bad is entirely subjective. I personally find the voice-over awful, you find it good -- good for you! The StackExchange question is about how can I avoid using the voice-over, but have English subtitles instead.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Ah ok now I understand - you want Russian audio but English subtitles.

Comment: @Selvek Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.moddb.com/mods/translations/downloads/winter-of-death-english-all-in-one) well-received English translation of the mod 'Winter of Death: Ultimatum', has English subtitles. Since I do not own the game I cannot test them myself, but in the folder *gamedata/configs/text/eng/*, I found English dialogue files (such as *st_dialog_jupiter.xml*).

I presume you can install the Russian version of S.T.A.L.K.E.R.: Call of Pripyat via Steam, and copy the contents of the aforementioned folder of this mod to the */text/* folder of the game.

Note however, since they come in a folder specifically named after the language ('eng'), that the Russian version might have its text in *gamedata/configs/text/rus*, so you might need to replace the files in there (make sure to back them up first, since Steam's *Verify Integrity of Game Files* might not be able to differentiate between all of them).

An alternative could be editing the *localization.ltx* file in *gamedata/configs/*:

> [string_table] 
>   
> language  = eng

The last line in all probability reads *language = rus* and needs to be switched with this.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I will take a look at that thing. Is the translation only available for the mod, or also for the vanilla game?

Comment: I presume it's for the entire game, but cannot vouch for it.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Have you tried this yet?