# Is it possible to play the S.T.A.L.K.E.R. series in Russian or Ukrainian with English translation?

Tags: stalker-series

At least Shadow of Chernobyl mixes heavily accented English with Cyrillic speech. I would much rather play in Russian or Ukrainian (whichever can be considered as the original language track) with full English subtitles, like I did with the Metro series.

I don't remember if the game world was ever fully localized (signs, book covers, written words on walls, etc.), but I prefer the Cyrillic alphabet even if no translation can be provided (without mods).

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321228/). I gave an answer there, but never got around to trying it myself, and the OP never got around to it too, I guess.

Comment: Looks like those two questions are actually duplicated of each other. [Is there a way to add English subtitles for S.T.A.L.K.E.R.: Call of Pripyat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321228/is-there-a-way-to-add-english-subtitles-for-s-t-a-l-k-e-r-call-of-pripyat)

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy: Apparently I didn't consider the other question as a duplicate as I requested a full localization, but the essence is the same. Accepted.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy: I just noticed that the question is about Call of Pripyat while this one is about the entire series... I may clear the dupllicate flag once I know how.

Comment: @user598527 I doubt there is actually a way to do it for the entire series, so I'd wait till you actually find a solution then. Or change this question to be about one other specific game.